# Алгоритм анализа данных и определения выбросов

Tags: математика, статистика, анализ-данных, аналитика

Есть некоторый набор данных по нескольким параметрам. Другими словами двумерный массив, где значения во вложенных массива - некоторые значения параметров.
Изобразить можно так:

```
       / p1 / p2 / p3 /
-------------------------------
A    / 4   / 5   /  3   /
B    / 4   / 10 /  1  /
C    / 1   /  6  /  2  /
```

В данном случае у нас есть 3 вектора: А, В, С.
У меня задача сложнее, параметров больше 20, различных векторов 1000+.

Задача: проанализировать эти данные, найти выбросы среди них.

Мне на ум приходит 2 идеи:

1. Подсчитать косинусное расстояние между всеми векторами, однако что с этим делать дальше я не особо понимаю..
2. Пройтись по каждому параметру, посмотреть среднеквадратическое отклонение, посмотреть выбросы по каждому параметру, но зачем...

*Вопрос*: как можно проанализировать датасет, что считать за выбросы и как их найти?

Comment: Что такое "проанализировать"? "что считать за выбросы" — это к вам вопрос, ведь это постановка задачи, а не решение

Comment: @dIm0n "проанализировать" - скорее, как комплексно подойти к решению данной задачи (не смотреть по отдельности на каждый параметр) . Про выбросы та же ситуация. Можно искать выбросы по каждому параметру отдельно, а как сделать по-другому?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, можно ждать, какие еще идеи придут на ум. А можно посмотреть, как люди решают вашу задачу, причем -  в основном не по наитию, а после того, как изучат соответствующую теорию.
Ключевое слово "Outliers detection" или "Anomalies detection"
Можете начать отсюда:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/outlier-detection-theory-visualizations-and-code-a4fd39de540c
- https://baguzin.ru/wp/opredelenie-vybrosov/
- https://www.statisticshowto.com/find-outliers/
- https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-statistics-to-identify-outliers-in-data/
- https://towardsdatascience.com/ways-to-detect-and-remove-the-outliers-404d16608dba
- https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/02/outlier-detection-python-pyod/
- https://towardsdatascience.com/outlier-why-is-it-important-af58adbefecc
- https://machinelearningmastery.com/model-based-outlier-detection-and-removal-in-python/
- [https://dyakonov.org/2017/04/19//поиск-аномалий-anomaly-detection/](https://dyakonov.org/2017/04/19//%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9-anomaly-detection/)

Далее -  по ссылкам.

Будут вопросы - обращайтесь.